# Gutenberg component in a plugin admin

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I would like to use Gutenberg components to develop my plugin admin but I faced some issues regarding some of components like `ColorPalette`.

I tried to ask the question on Gutenberg repository but they could not help me regarding it, and you can find the issue with details and images [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/16417#issuecomment-508908193).

Please let me know do you any experience regarding using Gutenberg components in a plugin admin? How can I solve the `ColorPalette` issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as the person who closed the issue explained, you need to wrap your code with `PopoverProvider` in order for it to work correctly